# why some values are not being matched with its label in java/json?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am coming to an issue where I combine my hourly, biweekly, and annual rows to show in one object, but for some reason, biweekly, and annual values are the same as my hourly values. I just want get my biweekly values, and annual values to match with its rate_type rows. Can anyone help me fix this issue. thanks for the help.

here is my result:

```
    [
    {
        "id": "7777",
        "label": "NONE",
        "pay_grade_description_link": "7777",
        "mou": "00",
        "mou_description": "NONE",
        "Hourly": [
             "      $10.00",

        ],
        "Biweekly": [
            "      $10.00",

        ],
        "Annual": [
            "      $10.00",

        ]
    }
```

> Jsonserializer:

```
    public class AutoCompleteSerializer extends StdSerializer<AutoComplete> {

    public AutoCompleteSerializer() {

        this(null);
    }

    public AutoCompleteSerializer(Class<AutoComplete> t) {
        super(t);
    }


    public void serialize(AutoComplete value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {


        jgen.writeStartObject();

        jgen.writeStringField("id", value.jobClassCd + value.payGrade);
        jgen.writeStringField("label", value.jobClassTitle + value.jobClassCd + value.payGrade);
        jgen.writeStringField("pay_grade_description_link", value.jobClassCd);

        jgen.writeStringField("mou", value.mou);
        jgen.writeStringField("mou_description", value.mouDescription);


             List<String> jobs = Arrays.asList(nullIfWhitespace(value.step1),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step2), nullIfWhitespace(value.step3),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step4), nullIfWhitespace(value.step5),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step6), nullIfWhitespace(value.step7),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step8), nullIfWhitespace(value.step9),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step10), nullIfWhitespace(value.step11),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step12), nullIfWhitespace(value.step13),
                    nullIfWhitespace(value.step14), nullIfWhitespace(value.step15));



        jgen.writeObjectField("Hourly", jobs);
        jgen.writeObjectField("Biweekly", jobs);
        jgen.writeObjectField("Annual", jobs);


         jgen.writeEndObject();


    }


private String nullIfWhitespace(String steps) {
        return steps.trim().equals("") ? null : steps;

    }



}
```

Comment: Looks like you are putting the same list, `jobs`, against 'Hourly' 'Biweekly' and 'Annual' that is why you might be seeing the same result.

Comment: Hello @SB can you share your original data or recheck that 'Hourly' 'Biweekly' and 'Annual'  have different values

Comment: @PatelRomil they do have different values.